# NodeJS JSON.parse throwing error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am simply using `JSON.parse` in node.js for a array of hexadecimal id

```
'["5682940386289d593130ed98","568293fe86289d593130ed97","568293f486289d593130ed96"]'
```

getting an error,

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' .

Even when i try passing the array as  :

```
'[5682940386289d593130ed98,568293fe86289d593130ed97,568293f486289d593130ed96]'
```

it throws the error ,

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token d .

weird behaviour to understand. Anybody suggestion about where I can read about the same.

Comment: Check the `typeof` values which you are attempting to parse. It must be string representation of the `json`

Comment: The first stringified array you gave should pass `JSON.parse` without error and results in an array. Is that indeed your full string you were parsing in your codebase?

Comment: i too agree with Tao... it works.

Comment: @Tao P. Rr :  my question is not for front-end javascript , I specifically mention it is for nodeJs you can check the below answer for details.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar : check the below answer

Answer (score 2):

Your string starts and ends with a ' for some reason, it actually looks like this:

```js
// run this snippet
// to see the error
var str = '\'["5682940386289d593130ed98","568293fe86289d593130ed97","568293f486289d593130ed96"]\'';
try {
  JSON.parse(str);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  snippet.log(err.stack);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I don't know how you build/get this string but you could strip the ending and starting ' from it by using the following code:

```js
var str = '\'["5682940386289d593130ed98","568293fe86289d593130ed97","568293f486289d593130ed96"]\'';
str = str.replace(/^'|'$/g, ''); // remove ' before parsing
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: `replace(/^'|'$/g, '')`

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks, I forgot about these anchors.